# Determine if the following are always true.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine, with explanation, if the following are always true.

a) If G is a group, $N \lhd G$, G/N is Abelian, and N is Abelian, then G is Abelian.

b)If G is a group, $N \lhd G$ and $G/N \cong M$, then $G \cong N\times M$.

c) If G is cyclic, then Aut(G) is cyclic.

I am not sure about any of them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean $G/N\cong M$

Answer (score 3):

a) False. Look at $S_3$.

b) False. Look at $S_3$.

c) This is true. If $|G|=n$, then $Aut(G)$ is isomorphic to the group of unit of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Look at some non-abelian groups of small order you know.  You'll either find a counterexample, or hopefully start seeing what the proof should be.

b) Has a typo I'm not sure how to correct, since you use both $N$ and $M$ repeatedly, but only $N$ is defined.  I'm fairly sure whatever the correct statement is will be false.

c) What must an automorphism do to a generator?  You could also look up automorphisms of abelian groups, which would at least tell you if this is true or false.